# How to display result of map in two different columns

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a task, but i couldnt get the solution for it in reactjs. I would like to show the result in two columns like: So every next element should be added in the second column, but the first column should be limited to 2 rows.

```
item 1 | item 4
item 2 | item 5
       | item 6
```

When i loop through the array the columns are getting divided into equal order, but as you see in the diagram i need to split them in 2:3 ratio.
I am giving the sandbox link here on what i have tried so far.

```js
// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  render() {
  const secondaryNav = [
    {
      title: "Games",
      name: ["Roadrash", "Prince of Persia", "Counter Strike"]
    },
    {
      title: "Resources",
      name: ["Images", "Videos", "E-books"]
    },
    {
      title: "Shop",
      name: ["Shop now"]
    },
    {
      title: "Account",
      name: ["Log In", "Register"]
    },
    {
      title: "Support",
      name: ["Email", "Call Us", "Get a callback"]
    }
  ];
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {secondaryNav.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <h3>{ item.title }</h3>
                <ul>
                  {item.name.map((items, i) => {
                    return <li>{items}</li>
                  })}
                </ul>
              </div>)
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[SANDBOX](https://ueknl.csb.app/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the css on it and also you could slice your array as you like.

this is the piece of the code

```
<div className="row">
  {secondaryNavData.slice(0, 2).map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        <ul>
          {item.name.map((items, i) => {
            return <li>{items}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
<div className="row-2">
  {secondaryNavData.slice(2, 5).map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        <ul>
          {item.name.map((items, i) => {
            return <li>{items}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Try this codesandbox based on yours for the full code with the css
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-grass-nmeux

Answer (score 2):

`slice` can help us slice the array between `(0,2)` and `(2,5`) indices and accordingly we can map over the divs. We don't need `row` class coming from bootstrap for this use-case. Can simply replace it with `col` as well.

**Updated question sandbox -**
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-black-4m4ii?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Actually i also needed every new element to be added in the second column.

Comment: Can you update these requirements in the question itself ?

Comment: Yes Updated the question too

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers there, but for I wanted to add a CSS-only one. In my case some of the element could eventually render null, so with Javascript I was ending up with one column having 6 elements and the other one only two.

I thought of a .filter() where I rendered every element to see whether they were `null` or not but that seemed very ineficient.

Dug a bit and ended up using the following CSS:

```css
.container {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.container > * {
  /** Avoid CSS splitting any elements in two */
  break-inside: avoid;
  
  /** Demo */
  background-color: #f0f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```